# Run $Path command in Terminal in a python script

Tags: python, terminal, ipython, jupyter-notebook

i use ipython notebook and I want to call a terminal command: 
`fft <in> <out>`

my "fft" is in my $PATH so using a terminal, this would work.

How can I run this command in my ipython notebook?

---

the problem is that my fft executable is in my $PATH folder, and python won't recognize this

Comment: have you tried `!fft`?

Comment: Doesnt work. It says `!fft not found`

Comment: Else you can always do a call to `subprocess` (https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module) and have the command executed by actual python commands. `subprocess.run(["fft"])`.

Comment: `import subprocess 

subprocess.run(["fft"], shell=True)`
Gives me the error:
`'module' object has no attribute 'run'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution:

```
import os    
os.system("xterm -e 'bash -c \"fft -i 3 AddedK AddedK_ifft; exit -f exec bash\"' ")
```

`xterm` opens a new terminal

`fft ...;` calls the function fft

`exit -f` closes the terminal